# Cannot view GitHub documentation

Tags: google-chrome, github, documentation

I cannot view GitHub documentation (https://docs.github.com/*) in Chrome 79.0.3945.117
(MacOS 12.0.1): I see only a blank page.

In the Chrome console, I see the following errors:

1. DOMException: Failed to execute 'sendBeacon' on 'Navigator': sendBeacon() with a Blob whose type is not any of the CORS-safelisted values for the Content-Type request header is disabled temporarily. See http://crbug.com/490015 for details.
2. DOMException: Failed to execute 'sendBeacon' on 'Navigator': sendBeacon() with a Blob whose type is not any of the CORS-safelisted values for the Content-Type request header is disabled temporarily. See http://crbug.com/490015 for details.
3. A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
4. Error rendering page:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'cookies' of undefined
5. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Please specify a more specific page you cannot visit (as `*` is not valid) and it might be that just specific pages are not available.

Comment: albert, specific pages are https://docs.github.com/en, https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template, https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests, https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks, etc

Comment: FYI I can reach te pages, under Windows, on FireFox and Chrome ( 96.0.4664.45 ) niht it be that your version is a bit old? Or might it be that on your system some policies have been set that aren't statisfied?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed a newer version of Chrome (96.0.4664.55) and now I can see the GitHub Documentation Page (thanks @albert for the suggestion).
I was sure that Chrome Automatic Update was activated but clearly I was wrong.
Now I have to check from time to time whether Chrome Automatic Update works propertly.